# Debug Chromium Embedded Framework using visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, chromium, chromium-embedded

I want to surf deep and make changes to chromium embedded framework. For that I want to understand and debug its code by setting debugging points. Can anyone help me by giving instructions. that how to debug the chromium code with visual studio?

[Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef)

**EDIT**

I have download and build using "Automated Git Workflow" and also able to create ".sln" file of cef and added project in visual basic 2013. But when I build and run the code it is giving error

**"target architecture x64 is only supported on x64 host"** I have set target x64 and my machine is also have 64 windows.

Comment: It's no different than with other projects... Compile and run the source code and inspect it as it's running

Comment: I am using visual studio first time, so can you please tell me how to add it as a project in visual studio so that  I can debug it.

Comment: [here all the info you need](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding)

Comment: Thanks but I am referring the same site and also downloading the visual studio. But the thing is after installing depot tools and python using gitclient, it asks to fetch chromium code, which is I think download the 6GB to 22GB of code. I don't want all branches and want only particular one branch of code. So can you tell me the way to download only one branch of code so it should do minimum download.

Comment: Look at the section ["Automated Git Workflow"](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding#markdown-header-automated-git-workflow) in the link @Sga gave you.  You should be able to run that and it will download only the branch you specify.  I did that recently with 2171.

Comment: Last night I was trying with  Manual downloading and building the project. So till now I downloaded whole chromium code.

Comment: while doing "gclient sync --revision refs/tags/39.0.2171.95 --jobs 16" after long time I am getting "Syncing project: 100%" "Error: Command git remote update returned non-zero exit status 1"

Comment: Thanks #PhysicalEd. I have used the automated workflow but it is taking very long time to download, it already taken 24 hours and still downloading.

Comment: I have used "Automated Git Workflow" and also able to create ".sln" file of cef and added project in visual basic 2013. But when I build and run the code it is giving error "target architecture x64 is only supported on x64 host" I have set target x64 and my machine is also have 64 windows.

Comment: Please have a look at this question, [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931279/building-and-debugging-chromium-using-visual-studio-giving-module-machine-type). It is I think related to visual studio.