# Call Ninja.exe exited with code1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ninja, gn

I am trying to create an application in which I am using gn. I tried creating the .exe file with the following command.

```
gn gen out --ide=vs
ninja -C out
```

Then, I opened the generated solution file and tried building it, but I am getting an error which says `MSB3073 The command "call ninja.exe -C path\to\sln\file  main" exited with code 1.  main    path\to\sln\file`

I am confused why this error is coming. I have searched over many places for this but didn't get any desired results.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Is ninja on your path? Have you checked for a more detailed error message?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Can you tell how to put ninja on path or any reference for it?

Comment: @drescherjm Ok, So what can be the possible solutions?

Comment: I don't think we have enough information for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution revolves around GN with ninja for Cross-platform development.

We use the following commands for creating build files:-

```
gn clean out //Cleans the build files
gn gen out 
gn gen --ide=vs out  //Creates .sln file for the build files
ninja -C out  //Build Files
```

But to build using visual studio, by default, the architecture is set to x32 while hinders ninja to build using visual studio.

So, we need to modify the architecture to x64 for ninja to build using visual studio which can be done using the following:-

```
SET GYP_DEFINES=target_arch=x64
```

Further reference can be taken from this link, if you are building on chromium:-

[Chromium ninja build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931279/building-and-debugging-chromium-using-visual-studio-giving-error-error-lnk1112)

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.